# Javascript parameters do not show methods / hints in VSCode

Tags: javascript

When using a variable after i click, it will give me the methods that are available that I can use. but using parameters it doesn't show anything. is there a way I can fix this in vscode?

[image: Here is an exmaple]

```
function stringIncludes(str) {
    str.//doesnt show anything
    let string = "string"
    string.//shows all the methods for strings
}
```

I was thinking of specifying the parameters data structure but I don't think you can do that in javascript if you can please let me know how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens in because VSCode has no idea what type the variable `str` is.

For VSCode you can use [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/) to help IntelliSense understand what you are doing in Vanilla JavaScript (when not using TypeScript)

For your example, it could look like this:

```
/**
 * Determine if string includes...
 * @param {string} str - string to check
 */
function stringIncludes(str) {
    str.//doesnt show anything
    let string = "string"
    string.//shows all the methods for strings
}
```